# Blocking call inside a using block doesn't prevent the scoped object from being disposed

Tags: c#, block, using

My NetworkStream id being disposed even though the calling thread hasn't left the using scope, I'm getting:

> "Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream"

I was under the impression that if I'll block the calling method that starts the event subscription the NetworkStream will be kept alive, what am I doing wrong?

```
using (var tcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient())
{

    using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    {
        //Edit: start of the code that was missing from my original question    
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {            
            var someVal = Login(sr, sw);
        }
        //Edit: end of the code that was missing from my original question    

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(networkStream, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true })
        {
            someObj.BlockingCall(sw); //calling some blocking call
        }                        
    }        
}


internal class SomeObj
{
    private StreamWriter _sw;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;
    internal SomeObj()
    {   
        _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);            
    }
    internal void BlockingCall(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        try
        {
            _sw = sw;                
            dataProvider.OnHighFrequencyEvent += DataProvider_OnHighFrequencyEvent;

            _manualResetEvent.WaitOne(); // here it blocks
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error subscribing to dataProvider", ex);
        }
    }

    private void DataProvider_OnHighFrequencyEvent(IData data)
    {            
            try
            {
                _sw.WriteLine(data.Payload); //here the exception occurs
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

as Peter have said, there's a code missing (thought I was doing it more readable by removing it) I've added it above with a comment and apparently this is what caused the issue, can u explain why? it's only disposing the StreamReader...

Comment: First of all, the using block does not prevent the object from being disposed, it only guarantees calling the Dispose method when execution of the block is completed (either successfully or with an exception). What happens in your case probably is that the remote end (the Other end of the socket, your client) is disconnected.

Comment: Yes, if the only code that was present was the code you show here, you wouldn't get the exception. But you're getting the exception. So you have some code somewhere else that is disposing the object. But you didn't bother to show that code, never mind a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so we can't help you.

Comment: It only Disposes the StreamReader, which closes the underlying stream: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/AsyncStreamReader.cs,e21134ed92dd9d7d

Comment: [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx): "The StreamReader object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamReader.Dispose is called." - so don't try to use two separate `StreamXxx` objects on the same underlying stream. (or if you do, make sure that their lifetimes are aligned w.r.t `Dispose`).

Comment: thank you Damien, you're correct! If you want, post as an answer and I'll give you the credit